# How can I target the .js HelloWorld File I made with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working through "NodeBeginner.org".

With extremely little command line experience I'm failing to run my first file.
I've managed to run "console.log('helloworld');" from the console by entering in JUST that line.

If it looks like I need to learn a more about CLI, then please point me in a direction for what concepts are important for node.js

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Adding your code that you're having trouble with in the future should help others to pick out any issues your having.

Comment: you're seeing all of it O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should type `node helloworld.js` in command line, not in Node interactive shell.

In interactive shell, you can execute JS statement directly like input `console.log('Hello world')`

Comment: oh. accept is the green checkmark. grand.
thanks Wing Leong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run your file from inside the node CPI shell.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit the node CLI shell.

Then use the following command inside your projects working directory:

```
node helloworld.js
```

Comment: thanks. this turned out to be the issue. I've typed out the whole path to my dropbox. project. Is this something i'll have to do every time?t

Comment: Yes, you will have to do this every time you want to run your project. Be sure to accept this answer if this answer helped you :)